Multiple create action on a page
I'm working on a project using Laravel Filament v3. I have an operational order form, but I want to add two buttons at the bottom of the page. These buttons would allow users to create a new customer or feature if they don't exist.
The buttons partially function as intended; they display a form when clicked. However, the issue is that the same form is displayed regardless of which button is pressed. Therefore, the 'New Customer' button should display a different form than the 'New Feature' button.
namespace App\Filament\Resources\OrderResource\Pages;

use App\Filament\Resources\OrderResource;
use Filament\Actions;
use Filament\Resources\Pages\CreateRecord;
use Filament\Actions\CreateAction;
use Filament\Forms\Components\TextInput;
use Filament\Forms\Components\Textarea;
use Filament\Forms\Components\Select;
use App\Models\Customer;
use App\Models\Feature;

class CreateOrder extends CreateRecord
{
    protected static string $resource = OrderResource::class;

    protected function getFormActions(): array
    {
        // Form action for Customer model
        $customerFormAction = CreateAction::make()
            ->model(Customer::class)
            ->form([
                TextInput::make('Company_Name')->required(),
                TextInput::make('Company_Ref')->hidden(),
                TextInput::make('VAT_No')->label('VAT Number'),
                TextInput::make('Address_Line_1')->required(),
                TextInput::make('Address_Line_2'),
                TextInput::make('Address_Line_3'),
                TextInput::make('Address_Line_4'),
                TextInput::make('Postcode')->required(),
                TextInput::make('Telephone_no')->required(),
                TextInput::make('Fax_no'),
                TextInput::make('Mobile_No'),
                TextInput::make('Email')->email(),
                TextInput::make('Web'),
                TextInput::make('Contact'),
                TextInput::make('Artwork_Contact'),
                Textarea::make('Memo')->autosize(),
            ]);

            $featureFormAction = CreateAction::make()
            ->model(Feature::class)
            ->form([
                TextInput::make('Rep_No'),
                TextInput::make('Feature_Name')->required(), 
                Select::make('Issue')
                    ->options(function () {
                        return \App\Models\Publication::where('Status_Live', true)
                            ->pluck('Title', 'Publication');
                    })
                    ->required(),
                TextInput::make('Main_Contractor'),
                Textarea::make('Feature Notes')->autosize(),
            ]);
     
            return array_merge(parent::getFormActions(), [
                $customerFormAction,
                $featureFormAction,
            ]);
    }
  
    protected static bool $canCreateAnother = false;

